# Creating a cricle button on android studio using a drawable ressource (but the color won't show)

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, button, drawable

I am new to android Studio and I am trying to create a rounded button using a drawable ressource. Here is the code I used and it seems to work fine when looking to the preview :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <stroke android:color="@color/grey" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
        <size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/>
    </shape>
```

[1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjiwd.png

The thing is that when I use this design in my layout (using the background), the shape will apply but not the colors and I don't know why. Here is the code and what it does :

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp">
    
            <Button
    
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:text="Play"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Stop"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[2]  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqGCB.png

I know I could use another shape like rectangle and do some modifications on the angle but I found it frustrating not being able to use the oval shape.

What should I do in order for this to work ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you need to use ImageButton instead. And also change the android:background property to android:src

Comment: I did thought about it but then i can't add text to it and can't seem to be able to do it from the drawable